# How to make embed YouTube video play full screen when play button clicked on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, web, youtube-iframe-api

I'm building a website that allow users to watch embed YouTube videos.

For now, I can only make the videos [play inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFXRK.png) on my website.

However, I want the videos be played on mobile devices which popped up as full screen and played both portrait and landscape.

Is it a way to make it just like YouTube's website on mobile devices?

When the play button is clicked, [the view will be full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Kmh.png).

Comment: Idk about other mobile devices or on web for that matter, but on iOS devices, you can use [URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html) in your web code, to directly open that video in Youtube app.

Comment: thanks, but I don't want users to switch to another app. it's better to make them stay in my website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no JS interface for embedded url to return call on click of player. So android app can not handle this event.